# GHCI asking for type or value namespaces?

Tags: haskell

When asking `GHCI` for `type` or `info`, which namespace is used for names and expressions?

```
 :type <expr>                show the type of <expr>
 :info[!] [<name> ...]       display information about the given names
                             (!: do not filter instances)
```

I'm not sure what I'm asking for and what does the following signature mean.

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State> :t StateT
StateT :: (s -> m (a, s)) -> StateT s m a
```

Is first `StateT` from value namespace and second from type namespace in the response line?

Comment: Type signatures are of the form `expression::type`. All values to the left of `::`, all types to the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `:t`[`ype`] always uses the value namespace
- `:k`[`ind`] always uses the type namespace
- `:i`[`nfo`] uses both, displaying all matching identifiers. For instance,

  ```
  Prelude> data Q = A
  Prelude> data A = Q
  Prelude> :i Q
  data A = Q  -- Defined at <interactive>:5:10

  data Q = A  -- Defined at <interactive>:4:1
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Since it only makes sense to ask for the types of expressions, you can be confident that `:t StateT` is using the expression namespace. Likewise, in a type ascription/declaration `foo :: bar`, the left hand side `foo` is always an expression and the right hand side `bar` is always a type. So as you say, in

```
StateT :: (s -> m (a, s)) -> StateT s m a
```

the first `StateT` is from the expression namespace, and the second `StateT` is from the type namespace. If you want to ask for the "type" of a type-level expression, you can use the `:kind` command (or `:k` for short), in which case the argument is always a type-level expression. Thus:

```
Control.Monad.State> :k StateT
StateT :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

Here the `::` denotes a *kind* ascription, so in `foo :: bar`, `foo` is a type-level expression and `bar` is a kind-level expression.

Usually it is possible to tell -- completely syntactically -- which namespace a given name is from, but the `:info` command is a bit special. When you ask for info on a name that appears in both namespaces, it gives you info about both.